# How create init VC from Storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have to create init VC from UIStoryboard in AppDelegate.

I used .instantiateInitialViewController() but I always get nil.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = .init(name: "Storyboard", bundle: nil)
    if let vc = storyBoard.instantiateInitialViewController() {
        window?.rootViewController = vc
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    return true
}
```

My project:

[image]

I don't have 'ViewController' file (and class too). Why I always get 'nil' in vc? How it work? Please explain.

Comment: Do you have an initial view controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason for `storyBoard.instantiateInitialViewController` to return nil is because your storyboard does not have an initial view controller. You can select a VC in the storyboard and check "Is Initial View Controller" to make it an initial view controller:

[image]

Note that if you set your storyboard as the "Main Interface" in your project settings, then the initial VC will show up automatically.

To avoid this, change this setting to an empty string:

[image]

Alternatively, you can give your VC an identifier in the identity inspector:

[image]

And use `instantiateViewController(withIdentifier)` instead

```
storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyVC")
```

Comment: @MrTishman Not unless your storyboard is the main storyboard. If your storyboard is the main storyboard, then yes, the initial VC will be shown automatically.

Comment: Ok, now I see. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
let navigationController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Storyboard", bundle: nil)
    let messageVC = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "YourViewControllerID")
    navigationController.pushViewController(messageVC, animated: true)
```

Comment: I know about this way, now I'm trying understand how work with .instantiateInitialViewController()

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I'm always navigate between view controllers with these codes ,

```
  let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewControllerStoryBoardId") as! YourViewControllerClass
        vc.page_idenifier = "Home page"//eg:- Passing data
        navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```